# Which emails are send by schedule?

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail, email-scheduler

I'm having some emails been sent by my Magento 2, and others not, I'm suspecting that the Magento has sent just the transactional emails sent immediately, not the emails by cron schedule, even with my cron configured.

Which are the transactional emails send via cron schedule and immediately (eg. contact email)?